# opening csv file and writing

Tags: python, file, csv

please help me 
what is my code problem??
my code writing name , mean(grades) in out put

```
import csv
from statistics import mean
with open('C:/Users/sina/Desktop/python pt/jalase19.csv' , 'r') as fo:
reader = csv.reader(fo)
for row in reader :
    name = row[0]
    grades = list()
    for grade in row[1:]:
        grades.append(float(grade))
        with open('C:/Users/sina/Desktop/python pt/jalase20.csv' , 'w') as fw:
            fw.write("name , mean(grades)\n")
```

Comment: Anytime you have a line that ends in a colon, the next block should be indented.

Comment: What exactly is the "code problem"? What output are you expecting?

Comment: Read [mcve] guidelines.  Make sure your code is displayed on SO as written (correct indentation) by cut-n-pasting original, highlighting and hit CTRL-K to format as code.Provide sample input, and expected vs. actual output.  Describe what doesn't work and what you want.  Without these basics, it generates "guessing" answers.

Answer (score 1):

**You didn't do an indent after the "with" statement**

As described [here](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html) you have to do an indent after an "with" statement

Your code should look like that:

```
import csv
from statistics import mean
with open('C:/Users/sina/Desktop/python pt/jalase19.csv' , 'r') as fo:
    reader = csv.reader(fo)
    for row in reader :
        name = row[0]
        grades = list()
        for grade in row[1:]:
            grades.append(float(grade))
            with open('C:/Users/sina/Desktop/python pt/jalase20.csv' , 'w') as fw:
                fw.write("name , mean(grades)\n")
```

Also i think you meant **fw** instead of **f2**

Answer (score 0):

When opening your files you are missing indentation. See how the error points you to line 4? When opening a file using the [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) and anytime you are using a control statement (if, else, for, etc.) the next line must be indented.

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

with open('C:/Users/sina/Desktop/python pt/jalase19.csv', 'r') as fo:
    reader = csv.reader(fo)
    for row in reader:
        name = row[0]
        grades = list()
        for grade in row[1:]:
            grades.append(float(grade))
        with open('C:/Users/sina/Desktop/python pt/jalase20.csv' , 'w') as f2:
            f2.write("name , mean(grades)\n")
```